# Cannot see my database (schema) in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database-schema, mysql-workbench

I recently installed mysql5.5 to my Windows 7 (x64) machine. The first problem was I couldn't enter the cmd client with `mysql -u root -pmypass`. The cmd opens, yields an error for like 0.5s and closes. Than I created another user account with all privileges, it worked and I created a database. But now I want to export that database from MySQL Workbench but I cannot see that in the "select a schema" option. I tried "new connection" and "new server instance" none worked.
Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I am also trying to do it from "Edit Table Data" window. I can copy the table as a "CREATE" statement, but INSERT statements do not yield correct data.

Answer (score 0):

For the command line use WB too. In the list of connections you can right click for the context menu, which also offers to open a CLI window. In general, when you work with the CLI first open a normal CLI window (Start Menu -> Programs -> Accessories) and then try the mysql -u -p command. This way the CLI window won't close immediately and you can see what error message came out.

For WB: if you don't see a schema you know is there then probably the user you used to connect has no permissions to see it. So for tests try connecting as root and see if your schema is there. Import and Export of db objects (including entire schemas) is available in the admin section, not in the SQL IDE (where you found "Edit Table Data" etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this challenged and for a whole day I couldnt get it to work. In my case the sollution was setting permissions to the data directory. Running `chmod -v 0751 /var/lib/mysql` worked for me.